# Logo and store name hiding after using custom css in PayTab payment

Tags: jquery, payment-gateway

I am using paytabs for making users pay at our website. Everything was working fine at Mozilla and google chrome but at Microsoft edge, I was facing the issue of responsiveness that expiry date and CVV input fields were not looking proper that I solved by using 'float: left' in CSS property. But for using custom CSS I need to give the options in that function what is used to initialize the paytabs button.

Calling function is as similar as this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Paytabs("#express_checkout").expresscheckout({
        settings:{
            secret_key: "YOUR_SECRET_KEY",
            merchant_id: "YOUR_PAYTABS_MERCHANT_ID eg 10001234",
            amount: "10.00",
            currency: "USD",
            title: "Test Express Checkout Transaction",
            product_names: "Product1,Product2,Product3",
            order_id: 25,
            url_redirect: "https://www.YOURWEBSITE.com/return_url/",
            display_billing_fields: 1,
            display_shipping_fields: 1,
            display_customer_info: 1,
            language: "en",
            redirect_on_reject: 1,
            style:{
                css: "custom",
                linktocss: "https://www.yourstore.com/css/style.css",
            },    
        },
        customer_info:{
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Smith",
            phone_number: "5486253",
            country_code: "973",
            email_address: "john@test.com"            
        },
        billing_address:{
            full_address: "Manama, Bahrain",
            city: "Manama",
            state: "Manama",
            country: "BHR",
            postal_code: "00973"
        },
        shipping_address:{
            shipping_first_name: "John",
            shipping_last_name: "Smith",
            full_address_shipping: "Manama, Bahrain",
            city_shipping: "Manama",
            state_shipping: "Manama",
            country_shipping: "BHR",
            postal_code_shipping: "00973"
        },
        checkout_button:{
            width: 150,
            height: 30,
            img_url: "https://www.YOURWEBSITE.com/image/yourimage.jpg"
        },
        pay_button:{
            width: 150,
            height: 30,
            img_url: "https://www.YOURWEBSITE.com/image/yourimage.jpg"
        }
    });
</script>
```

After doing the same Logo and store name has been disappeared.
Expected result of pop up and this was coming before using custom CSS,

This is the image what is required

[image: This is the image what is required]

This is I am getting

[image: This is I am getting]

You can see store name and logo is missing.